# Import yfinance as yf

Tags: python, conda, yahoo, yfinance

Import yfinance as yf

Should run normally on conda but get this message

> ModuleNotFoundError Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>         1 import pandas as pd
>   ----> 2 import yfinance as yf
>         3 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yfinance'

Strange? As should be simple to install?

Comment: Is it installed with conda by default? If not, you probably need to install it, e.g. `conda install yfinance` or `pip install yfinance`.

Comment: have tried installing it and everything loads, go to load the package in notebook and got the no module msg?

Comment: Have you checked the notebook is using the correct environment? Also that title is... in need of some changes, do you think you can write a more descriptive one?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to install a python library is to:

- Open a `terminal` or `cmd` or `powershell` on your system.
- If using a virtual environment, activate the environment in your `terminal` or `cmd` or `powershell`.

For e.g., A virtual environment named `virtual_environment` created using `virtualenv` in `C://Users/Admin/VirtualEnvironments/` directory can be activated by opening a `terminal` or `cmd` or `powershell` in that directory and running `python -m virtualenv virtual_environment/Scripts/activate`. For ubuntu users, `python -m virtualenv virtual_environment/bin/activate`.

- To install a library named `python-library`, Run `pip install python-library`.
- To install a specific version of that library, like a library named `python-library` with version `2.0.1` can be installed by Running the command `pip install python-library==2.0.1`

Similarly, you simply have to run `pip install yfinance`

If you want to install a specific version, like `0.1.70`, then run command `pip install yfinance==0.1.70`.

If you have a `.whl` file of that library like `python-library.whl`, and want to install that wheel, then run command `pip install python-library.whl`.

Answer (score -1):

If you using anaconda, try downloan yfinance using Powershell Prompt.